# AngularJS - UI Does Not Update Well

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app. My controller looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.items = [];

  // ProfileUpdate: 0=Not Checked, 1=Checked, 2=Failed, 3=Succeeded
  $scope.items.push({
    name: 'Chicago Fire', players: [
      { number: 1, profileUpdated:0, name: 'Bill' },
      { number: 2, profileUpdated:0, name: 'John' }
    ]
  });

  $scope.items.push({
    name: 'Philadelphia Ice', players: [
      { number: 3, profileUpdated:0, name: 'Phil' },
      { number: 4, profileUpdated:0, name: 'Flo' }
    ]
  });

  ...

  $scope.currentTeamIndex = 0;
  $scope.currentPlayerIndex = 0;
  $scope.execute = function() {
        $http.get(playerRelatedUrl)
          .then(
            function(res) {
              $scope.items[$scope.currentTeamIndex].players[$scope.currentPlayerIndex].profileUpdated = 3;
            },
            function(err) {
$scope.items[$scope.currentTeamIndex].players[$scope.currentPlayerIndex].profileUpdated = 2;
            }
          )
  }
}]);
```

My intent is to iterate through each team and attempt to update the players profile. I want to reflect what is happening in the UI. In an effort to do this, I have the following in my view:

```
<button ng-click="execute()">Execute</button>
<div ng-repeat="team in items">
  <h2>{{team.name}}</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="player in team.players">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <div ng-switch="player.profileUpdated">
          <h3 ng-switch-when="0">Not checked yet</h3>
          <h3 ng-switch-when="1">Checking...</h3>
          <h3 ng-switch-when="2">Unable to update</h3>
          <h3 ng-switch-when="3">Updated!</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>{{player.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code renders correctly initially. However, when the execute button gets clicked, both "Checking..." and "Updated" appear. After a second or two, the word "Checking..." goes away. After some investigation, I learned my web service call is executing in ~90 ms. That would explain why the word "Updated" seems to appear so quickly. However, it does not explain why it takes so long for the word "Checking..." to go away.

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind showing the code that sets 'profile updated = 1' ? There is a chance it could be related to that logic. (sorry if I missed it in the current post). Cheers, [bro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1185425/jquery-mobile).

Comment: The devil may very well be in the details here, what type of data are we dealing with? 100 teams, 1000 teams? how many players per team. An ng-repeat with 100+ teams with 20 players per team will digest literally THOUSANDS of times.  ngRepeat is known to be an incredible bottleneck for performance.  If you have any watch statements on your scope they will be bound and unbound to data and running js potentially the same amount of times that the ng-repeat causes a scope digest

Comment: call $scope.$apply(); after setting player.profileUpdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS $http service returns a "promise", which means it returns a sort of placeholder for the return value immediately, but that placeholder will eventually be populated with the actual return value. That is, when the web service responds. Even if your web service call executes in 90 ms, that doesn't necessarily mean the promise has received its true value yet. It depends a bit on how you measured, I guess, but this *might* be the mechanism behind the "delay" you're experiencing. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http for reference.

Comment: his `ng-switch` gets updated (which happens in the `then`, so I would assume the promise has resolved). I'm actually having the same problem (using ng-if, not ng-switch) - where a seemingly competing conditions are shown together for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you have to work around the limitations of the framework. In this case, there is actually a potentially simpler solution.

In the JavaScript, why not set the status as a string instead of an integer?

```
$scope.execute = function() {
    $http.get(playerRelatedUrl)
      .then(
        function(res) {
                                                              // NOTICE THE STATUS IS A STRING HERE vvvvvvvvv
            $scope.items[$scope.currentTeamIndex].players[$scope.currentPlayerIndex].profileStatus= "Updated";
        },
        function(err) {
            $scope.items[$scope.currentTeamIndex].players[$scope.currentPlayerIndex].profileStatus = "Unable to update";
        }
      )
}
```

Then eliminate the switch from the HTML entirely. The code becomes much easier to read.

```
<button ng-click="execute()">Execute</button>
<div ng-repeat="team in items">
  <h2>{{team.name}}</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="player in team.players">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <div>
          <h3>{{player.profileStatus}}</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>{{player.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you really, really need to have an integer state variable for some reason, then write a little function and just do both:

```
function updatePlayerStatus( newValue ) {
    var statusUpdateStrings = [ "Not checking", "Checking", ... etc. ];
    var player = $scope.items[$scope.currentTeamIndex].players[$scope.currentPlayerIndex];
    player.profileUpdated = newValue;
    player.profileStatus= statusUpdateStrings[ player.profileUpdated ];
}

$scope.execute = function() {
    $http.get(playerRelatedUrl)
      .then(
        function(res) {
            updatePlayerStatus(3);
        },
        function(err) {
            updatePlayerStatus(2);
        }
      )
}
```

Comment: could you tell me why using an integer wouldn't be appropriate? and what is the limitation of the framework in this case?

Comment: I tried a simple demo (using integer and promises) and seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/26hw7evn/1/

Comment: @I_Debug I'm not trying to say one is or isn't appropriate. Sometimes we programmers make things more complicated than they need to be. We all do it. Of course, in a Stack Overflow posting it's hard to know all the OP's real constraints, so there may be a great reason for an integer state value. Or there may not be one. The limitation I was referring to was that the switch wasn't updated the way the OP expected. My code is one way of solving the problem. Yours looks really good, too. Why not post it as an answer?